# Is the /fill command usable for switch version?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

I tried to use it on minecraft Switch version and even used newest version of said command.
(1.13+) I couldn't tell if I was doing something wrong or not...

Answer (score 1):

The `/fill` command does work on switch, but make sure you are an operator and cheats are on so that you're allowed to use commands.

Here's the current syntax:

```
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 item_name
```

That's the basic command for `/fill` on the switch. For more information about advanced ways to use `/fill`, go to this website, scroll down to Fill Command and click on the Nintendo tab: https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/fill_command.php. There is also more information if you scroll down to Examples and click on the Nintendo tab.

If the command still doesn't work, try updating Minecraft on your Switch. It is currently at 1.14.30+.